# Can we derive PDAs inside a solana program?

Tags: pda, anchor-lang

Is there any function to generate PDAs using seeds manually?

I dont want to create PDAs using client modules but I want to create PDAs inside the rust functions in the contract/program.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 3):

you can use this piece of code :

```
let (address, bump) = Pubkey::find_program_address(
        &[
            ... your seeds ...
        ],
        ctx.program_id,
    );
```

please note that in anchor you can't use the address variable you get here like if it was passed as an account in the instruction (in a transfer for example).

in many cases, you need to have the account in your instruction's accounts